# C++: X does not name a type, while using typedef

Tags: c++, typedef

I have the following code:

"Class1.h"

```
class Class1{
public:
    typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> integral_image;
};
```

"exampleStruct.h"

```
#include "Class1.h"
struct s{
    typedef Class1::integral_image integral_image;
    integral_image a;
};
```

I get the following error: "Class1 does not name a type" but have no idea why?

Comment: where? end of struct and class, yes sorry I typed this out in the editor, I will edit

Comment: Provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is because Class1.h includes exampleStruct.h and exampleStruct.h includes Class1.h so the Class1 class cannot be compiled before the exampleStruct

Comment: If you put those two classes into the same file, it compiles just fine. Maybe it's really a recursive include problem as you stated. Always use forward declarations if you can!

Answer (score 2):

In the code

```
class Class1{
public:
    typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> integral_image;
}
```

the class definition lacks a **semicolon** at the end.

From the compiler's point of view it never ends…

Comment: Sorry, I typed this in to the editor instead of copy paste. My code has semicolons and I have edited the question to reflect this